# Auto-populate fields in terms of value populated in a previous field asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering but I don't get the way to solve my problem.

In fact, I want to auto-populate fields using the previous populated value for another field, in my form.
I think I have to use a script, that populate automatically the corresponding fields just when the focus is lost by the value populated for that field.

My model **Client** is:

```
public int ClientID{get;set;}
public string portfolio{get;set;}
public DateTime dateIn{get;set;}
public DateTime dateOut{get;set;}
public DateTime dateIn_cash{get;set;}
public DateTime dateOut_cash{get;set;}
public DateTime dateIn_equity{get;set;}
public DateTime dateOut_equity{get;set;}
```

So when the user populate the **dateIn** and **dateOut** properties and the focus is lost for dateOut, **dateIn_cash** and **dateIn_equity** have to automatically take the value of **dateIn** and the same for **dateOut**.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do an ajax request to the server to pull back the data.

Comment: can you give more details please I am not an expert in Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Here is a view markup example

```
@model Client 

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".inputsContainer input").datepicker();
         $("#dateIn").change(function(){  
             var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
             $("#dateIn_cash, #dateIn_equity").datepicker("setDate",date);
         });
         $("#dateOut").change(function(){  
             var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
             $("#dateOut_cash, #dateOut_equity").datepicker("setDate",date);
         });
    });
</script>

<div class='inputsContainer'>
    @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.dateIn)<br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.dateOut)<br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.dateIn_cash)<br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.dateOut_cash)<br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.dateIn_equity)<br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.dateOut_equity)<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! But how can I do with EditorFor method ? also I do not catch time = 'text' to what it corresponds ?

Comment: and how can I handle it using EditorFor ?

Comment: @intern EditorFor will generate inputs for you automatically with all needed attributes.

Comment: ok thanks but where can I find the script that you add at the top ? because I got an error for datePicker and also is the css file necessary ?  thank you again

Comment: jquery you can get from [there](http://jquery.com) and jquery ui from [there](http://jqueryui.com). Yes css is also needed for proper control design. Also datepicker must be called in lower case.

Comment: Excuse me I have downloaded it, but I can't find exactly the script that you have mentionned I have jquery-1.11.1.min.js and jquery-ui-min.js and I still get an error for the datepicker line

Comment: @intern have toy placed your scripts in subfolders specified in src property? Have you modified src filenames according to scripts that you downloaded?

Comment: yes i have the same name! But I think it does not recognize, I put the three references on the top of your code in the layout file and then I create a file with the script that you write in details and then I place @section with my scrit in the view and finally I render it using RenderSection at the bottom of the layout file. Do I miss something I don't why I think that I have right files but still datepicker not recognize. Thanks for your help

Comment: @intern is there any errors in browser console? Or maybe 404 for some files?

Comment: No it is a Miscrosoft JScript runtime error. Object doesn't support the property or method at line (".inputsContainer input").datepicker();

Comment: it means that external js files not correctly linked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61473/discussion-between-aleha-and-intern).